# RoR: Devise: After logging in, It redirects to the login page, how do I set redicect after login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

My routes file:

```
     get "public/index"

  get "public/timeline"

  devise_for :users
  match '/user' => "public#index", :as => :user_root
  namespace :user do
      root :to => "public#index"
  end
  devise_scope :user do
    get "/login" => "devise/sessions#new"
    get "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
  end

  root :to => 'public#index'
```

App Controller

```
Application Controller:
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      stored_location_for(resource) || root_url
  end
end
```

I want set the redirect to the root URL

I looked at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in and it didn't seem to work... maybe my routes are wrong?

EDIT:
The problem is with the logging in action.
here is the console output upon submission of login / password:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-10-25 13:31:16 -0400
  Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"NeWp8HyAg5p9kBOG9ff7U/Z34IGgUorEWNk9wGFn8T0=", "user"=>{"login"=>"DerNalia", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
Completed   in 20ms
  Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"NeWp8HyAg5p9kBOG9ff7U/Z34IGgUorEWNk9wGFn8T0=", "user"=>{"login"=>"DerNalia", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (2.3ms)
Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (6.1ms)
Rendered devise/menu/_registration_items.html.erb (0.7ms)
Rendered devise/menu/_login_items.html.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 199ms (Views: 20.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devise has a redirect hook for after sign in that you can override in your application controller to accomplish this. First you need to set the devise path to nil with:

```
def stored_location_for(resource)
  nil
end
```

Then you can assign your redirect like so:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  #path_to_redirect_to
end
```

And that's all there is to changing the redirect after loggin a user in.

**Edit**

I took a more in depth look at your code and found the login issue you were seeing. In you new session page you were having the login text box point to `:username` instead of `:login`, so change

```
<%= f.text_field :username %></div>
```

to this

```
<%= f.text_field :login %></div>
```

and that should then solve your login issue. I also noticed that in your Devise initializer file you were setting authentication keys on both `:login` and `:email`. This is not best practice for Devise and it is recommended that you change it to be strictly login.

Comment: didn't work. I think there may be a different cause. =\ if you care to, my code is all at https://github.com/DerNalia/SwingLX

Comment: I don't see anything in your code pointing to this problem. I do see that you are attempting to use a custom registration controller without telling devise that you are doing so.

Comment: `devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'yourcontrollername'`

Comment: all my registrations controller does is this class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  protected
  
    def after_update_path_for(resource)
      user_path(resource)
    end
end

Comment: it didn't fix my problem, any tips on trouble shooting?

Comment: I took a look at your code and found the problem. I posted in my original answer my corrections that will solve your problem.

Comment: still didn't work o.o, I'll update my question with the console output (I can't tell if anything is breaking, it appears to work (in the console, not the browser))  I really appreciate you taking the time to look through my code and help =D

Comment: false alarm, just needed to restart the server a couple times. it works. thank you! =D

Answer (score 2):

Did you read https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in ?

Comment: it could be that devise just isn't logging in, too

Comment: Where do you end up after login at the moment (which controller/action) ?

Comment: devise might be redirecting to the stored location. can you check the stored location's value. or just try returning nil from stored_location_for method to see if thats the issue.

Comment: I just get sent bock to sessions#new. Even if I just return root_url, it directs me back to session#new

Comment: I am trying to follow this guide. but doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with

Simply modify config/initializers/devise.rb file to have

config.scoped_views = true

(copied from [https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address))